# How to fix a hanging Logic Pro 9.1.5 on Snow Leopard?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, crash, performance, logic

I'm using Logic Pro 9.1.5 on my MacBook Pro (2.4 Ghz CPU, 7200 RPM HDD). I have Snow Leopard.

When I'm doing nothing special, working on my project, Logic sometimes freezes and I'm stuck with a 'spinning wheel of death' for hours.

I uploaded a hang log file to see if someone can help me diagnose this and find a fix.
[Hang log](http://www.scribd.com/doc/76040589/Hang-Log-Logic-pro-9-1-5)

Comment: What is your OS version? What steps are you performing that lead up to the problem?

Comment: snow leopard...nothing special.working on my project and the logic freeze with the spinning wheel of death for hours.

Comment: What audio interface are you using with Logic? Built-in audio in the MBP or a third-party external interface?

Comment: built in yet...

Comment: Have you tried upgrading to 9.1.7? There have been a number of hangs-on type bug fixes in the last two releases: http://support.apple.com/downloads/#logic pro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade to the latest version of Logic Pro and try running the program in 32 bits mode (at least for testing purposes).

Do a "Get Info" on the /Applications/Logic Pro and tick the Open in 32 bit checkbox.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your hang log (also called a sample). I have some experience reading samples for Mac OS X apps, and with Logic Pro 8. Unfortunately, I can't determine the problem from your log file.

If this problem is fully reproducible, it sounds like a bug. There may be nothing you can do aside from work on a different project or a new project within Logic. If you haven't already, report this to Apple via http://bugreport.apple.com/ .

Comment: thi have already send up to 10 reports but nothing happen..i'm watching the console and i see something little bit strange for me,very often.the messege is:"error for object incorrect checksum for freed object object was probably modified after being freed *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error to debug" maybe has something to do with it..

Answer (score 0):

Please consider creating a backup first.
Shutdown your mac and restart it in safe mode (on + shift).
Check the HDD for defects - disk utility will be sufficient for a quick check up.

read the other comments and do updates.
From your logfile i guess it might be the ram - the other options are quick to check for free so do it first.
Replace ram if necessary!